# Module name "tap" breaking karma testing

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Morning,

I'm setting up a new suite of Karma tests on a dummy application but have hit a-bit of roadblock. I've initialized the karma.conf.js file but when i run karma I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "tap" has not been loaded yet for context:     
_. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
at 
/Users/Andrew/sites/mine/FlowMyAngular/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:140
```

I went to the requirejs site and it explained the following:

> This occurs when there is a require('name') call, but the 'name' module has not been loaded yet.
>
> If the error message includes Use require([]), then it was a top-level
>   require call (not a require call inside a define() call) that should
>   be using the async, callback version of require to load the code

Ok - but the thing is I can't find where this require action is happening in the code - a project wide search for it returned nothing. All I know about tap is that it's a framework that can be used in karma to output TAP from tape.

Has anyone else come across this error or know how I can get around it? Here's my karma.conf.js file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Oct 29 2015 09:59:59 GMT+0000 (GMT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'node_modules/requirejs/require.js',
      '**/*.test.js',
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultanous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem actually occurred because of what I was setting in the karma.conf.js file for the location of the tests. This line:

```
'**/*.test.js',
```

was essentially attempting to pull in unwanted/unneeded files when running karma leading to the error described above. One solution to this could be to move all unit tests into one folder, however this would go against best practice when it comes down to project structure.

To fix it I kept all my tests alongside the code they are testing and changed the line to:

```
'app/js/**/*.test.js'
```

Job done.